# Is it possible to return `this` from a AngularJS factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my application I have static helper "classes" that perform a large amount of logic for me, in this specific case this class is the messaging class and performs logic that requires access to three different services(factories).

The only factory that needs to reference this class is the networking factory, as when a certain packet is received I need to force the messaging to update it's databases from the server.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
angular.module('database', []).factory('$database', function() {
    // SQLite implementation

    return {
       // ...
    };
});

angular.module('networking', []).factory('$networking', ['$database', function($database) {
    // Websocket implementation
    if(packet.opcode == 8) {
        Messaging.update(this, $database);
    }

    return {
       // ...
    };
}]);

Messaging = {
    // Messaging implementation..
    update: function(networking, database) {
        if(networking === undefined) { ]
            console.log("Networking is undefined.");
            return;
        }

        if(database === undefined) {
            console.log("Database is undefined.");
            return;
        }

        // Messaging update implementation.
};
```

Unfortunately, the `Networking is undefined.` message is being presented when trying to call `Messaging.update(this, $database)` as shown above.

**NOTE:** I cannot simply inject the $networking implementation into a $scope and use it, because this is being handled on the "back end". This logic should be executed completely independent of the scope. This code should be executed whenever the server (Websocket implementation) sends a packet opcode of 8 to the client, regardless of scope. This execution is done completely in the background and the user wont even know it happens.

I am also using `Messaging.update` in other places (From the scope) where it is applicable, such as in the `MessagingController` when a user sends a message, I can call `Message.update` using the injected `$networking` service. Unfortunately injection isn't an option here.

**NOTE:** Creating the Messaging as a service implementation would create a dependency loop, as I have three services currently `file-cache, database, networking` and the messaging implementation requires functionality from all three. The network is required to fetch information about a user that isn't available in the local SQLite database when a message that is received. The file-cache is used to cache a users avatar image when a new thread is created, and ofcourse the database is needed to store messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this pattern

```
angular.module('networking', []).factory('$networking', ['$database', function($database) {

    var net = {
        ....
    };

    // Websocket implementation
    if(packet.opcode == 8) {
        Messaging.update(net, $database);
    }

    return net;
}]);
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long, had to change around a lot of code to get this pattern to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well the factory method is not instantiated (as appose to service), the object you return is the same object you'll reference in other parts of your app. So you can't reference it with 'this'. You can do something like this (although I'm not sure it's a good practice):

```
//inside your factory
var fac = { //your factory object
};
return fac;
```

now you can replace 'this' with 'fac'.

What I would do instead, is to wrap your Messaging module as a service. In order to remove the circular dependency, you create another service/factory that will wrap all these services. I'm not sure exactly how, because I don't know your dependency graph, but that is what I do.